# Какие веб технологии/паттерны/подходы нужно знать разработчику?

Tags: веб-программирование

В интернете почти все курсы по веб програмированию начинают учить html/css/js/php. 
Но вот после собеседования где мне задали вопрос что такое REST, и услышали только молчание, интересует какие еще технологии/паттерны нужно знать и понимать разработчику ? Мой небольшой список:

- HTTP и методы
- REST
- MVC

Comment: ООП, патерны, sql - в любом случае спрашивать на собеседовании будут

Comment: Ну SQL и ООП это как раз понятно, а вот по паттернах можно уточнить какие именно ?

Comment: во первых какие виды патернов знаете вобще, ну а дальше по самому популярному списку...синглтон, фабрика, строитель, прототип... меня почему-то именно о них постоянно спрашивали

Comment: AJAX, WebSockets, RPC, микросервисы, React, Flux, SPA

Comment: Что получится в результате `i = 0; i += i++ + ++i;`. Чем плохи глобальные переменные. Что такое O(N) и что вообще из этой области бывает. И т.д. Собственно, это к тому, что за всем вышеперечисленным не надо забывать, что ещё программировать уметь надо...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от того уровня, на который Вы претендуете.
Приблизительный список тем, которые я затрагиваю, проводя собеседование с разработчиками (уточню, что имеются в виду PHP разработчики):

### **Паттерны**:

- формат "банды четырех"(GoF). Хотя бы основные.
- подробнее про порождающие паттерны. Зачем нужны всякие фабрики и фабричные методы?
- В продолжение темы порождающих паттернов: синглтон. Когда стоит применять? Когда не стоит? Особенности реализации на конкретном языке. Какие возникают с ним проблемы?
- Структурные и поведенческие паттерны. Декоратор, Заместитель, Посетитель, Компоновщик и пр.
- Вне формата банды четырех: паттерны объектно-реляционного отображения - Table Gateway, Row Gateway, Active Record, Data Mapper, Unit Of Work. В чем разница между Row Gateway и Active Record? Active Record и Data Mapper? Когда какой уместнее использовать?
- MVC, HMVC и пр.

### **Объектно-ориентированный дизайн:**

- принципы SOLID
- L и D в SOLID
- Dependency Injection
- Dependecy Injection Container и Service Locator. Что это? Какая между ними разница? Почему бы просто не создавать везде объекты через оператор `new`?

Можно еще долго расписывать, но... Самый практичный совет, который я могу Вам дать и который даст быстрый результат: *возьмите несколько популярных фреймворков, к примеру Yii2 и Symfony, и уделите пару месяцев своей жизни на то, чтобы следуя пошаговым урокам, коих более чем достаточно, попробовать написать несколько небольших проектов на каждом из этих фреймворков. Начиная с простых блогов, двигаясь к каким-либо более сложным задачам. По ходу дела, гуглите непонятные термины, которые Вам будут попадаться в уроках, перед сном читайте пару умных статеек на эти темы, чтобы углубиться в вопрос. Интереса ради попробуйте в одном из учебных проектов в качестве базы данных использовать НЕ MySql, а скажем PostgreSQL или хотя бы SQLite. Хотя бы для галочки.* Если будете прилежно следовать этому совету, то уже через месяц, Вы сами удивитесь насколько много нового и, главное, нужного для трудоустройства Вы узнаете. У вас появится опыт работы с несколькими ORM, вы будет знать, что такое REST, вы будете уметь ставить пакеты через composer, у Вас будет хоть и небольшое, но понимание чем между собой отличаются разные БД. А еще через месяц Вы вполне сможете претендовать на позицию junior или хотя бы fresher. Не забудьте еще посмотреть как работать с Git, залейте на GitHub свои учебные проекты (не забудьте указать ссылку на свой гитхаб-репозиторий в резюме) и вперед на собеседования. Главное потом старайтесь углублять свои знания и заполнять теоритеческие пробелы - разработчик, который хорошо владеет несколькими инструментами (знает пару библиотек и фреймворков) в перспективе не интересен, нужен человек, который постоянно готов учиться и развиваться.